# SQL injection filter evasion

Tags: php, sql-injection

During manual SQL injection testing I came upon this.

Is there any way to bypass these filters that supposedly prevent a `UNION` based attack?

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include('db.inc.php');

$id=strtolower($_GET['id']);

$counter = 0;
if(strpos($id,"union")!=false){
    $counter++;
}
if(strpos($id,"select")!=false){
    $counter++;
}

if($counter==2) {
    echo "Go Away Get a Life";
}else{ 
echo "<font color=green size=4>Query Coming is : ".$id."<br/></font>"; 
$query = "SELECT username,password FROM admin WHERE username='".$id."' ORDER BY 1";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Username : ".$row['username']."<br/>";
    echo "Password : ".$row['password']."<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

Also, what is the best way to prevent a `UNION` based SQLi attack?

Comment: Presumably id is an integer, so you could probably just cast it.  In general, blacklists are doomed to failure, because you can't exhaust all possible inputs - the usual SQL Injection route is to actually add conditions (like `= 0 OR 1=1`), which would slip right through here.  Really, though, you should be using [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/812837), which should stop it cold.

Comment: yea ur rite.. there are two things of my concern.. one is there any way we can use union select.. and 2nd thing u answered for integer.. but what for if id is string..?

Comment: ... it would depend on things like encoding - historically some attacks have gotten through because they used Unicode encoding that the db helpfully parsed/realized, but that the application didn't bother with.  Which is why the recommendation is to use parameterized queries - it doesn't care what the encoding is, it just stores it as a string).  Of course, then you have to remove anything like HTML (that's a different attack)...

Comment: Agree mostly with Clockwork-Muse, bu parameterized queries are just one solution. If you ave to deal with text at all, then checking for most of the SQL keywords is a better approach - but no substitute for proper isolation of data from SQL code.

Comment: thanks brother.. let me have a look at unicode attacks.. i never heard of it..

Comment: @symcbean - what do you mean about dealing with text?  IF it's a variable in SQL, that should still be part of a parameterized query.  If you're doing something with dynamic SQL (ignoring cases where the user is allowed to write the entire query), you're better off having an explicit whitelist of things allowed - there are ways to dodge application-layer validation of things that the db will be taken in by.  Or that get thrown out incorrectly - like, what about somebody searching for a book named `"A History of Unions" or something?

Comment: As you say dynamic SQL is a problem - it makes a massive performance difference to QBE if you build a custom query string. The key point is that blacklisting is always a poor solution - but whitelisting can only ever deal with a finite set of possibilities. Transforming an input to guarantee it's isolation (escaping) is a valid approach but requires a certain amount of discipline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit the [`!=` comparison](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison) of `strpos`’s return value and `false` as `0 != false` is false:

```
var_dump(0 != false); // bool(false)
```

This is due to implicit [type conversion to boolean](http://php.net/language.types.boolean#language.types.boolean.casting), where `0` is converted to `false`.

So you only need to ensure one of the `strpos` returns `0`, which means `$id` has to start with either `union` or `select`, for example:

```
id=union' union select 'foo', 'bar
```

Since `strpos($id,"union")` returns `0`, `strpos($id,"union")!=false` is false, `$counter` gets incremented only once and the query is executed with the injected SQL.

Comment: im impressed with ur answer @Gumbo.. let me check it.. i understand ur answer fully.. but le me check it.. i love ur concepts..

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, I think this can be bypassed using HPP (HTTP Parameter pollution), for example

```
?id=union select&id=union select ...
```

`counter==2` will be bypassed this way.

One other way I think could be using comments like

```
un/**/ion+se/**/lect
```

One other thing to note that to bypass this, we can proof the counter false using legitimate union select like in HPP or write union select in a way that it doesn't count like in 2nd example. I think the best way to use keyword filters is to use regular expressions.

Also double query injection is not considered.

Comment: bro.. thanx i was able to see how i can take this union select to my query.. but still query is not executing mean attacker is not successful at all..

Answer (score 1):

SQL Injection does not require the use of `union` or `select` . SQL injection means that the query structure itself has been altered by user input.

How about where `$id` is `' OR '1'='1`?

This will make your query become

```
SELECT username,password FROM admin WHERE username='' OR '1'='1' ORDER BY 1
```

which means all records will be returned.

The solution is to use [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) that treat variables as variables instead of part of the query structure.

Comment: And add casting to the `id`, as it must by an integer.

Comment: @ThoriumBR: That doesn't matter for the purposes of prepared statements, although it might be a good step in general to validate all parameters.

Comment: @Silverlight bro first question is how someone can still bypass these filters mean how can he take union select to my query.. and for 2nd part of the question thanx i will b using prepared statements..

Comment: @RummyKhan, the point is that using a UNION is not the only (or even the most common) way to use SQL injection.  Even if you improved your filter to perfect against the use of UNION, the above query would still work to get all passwords.

Comment: thanx Chris Murray yea i know methods of SQLinjection.. and im agreed to you completely.. but still thats not the answer of my Question..

Comment: @RummyKhan: I've updated your question as that point was not clear originally. Also add the @ sign if you want a user to be notified of your reply.

Comment: @Silverlight thanx brother..